# How do I utilize a single instance of a class over multiple contexts in C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to write a console RPG game in C#. I have a Party class containing a list of Heroes, `PlayerTeam`. I instantiate the Party class `PlayerTeam` in my `static void Main(string[] args`, and I am trying to write a new function creating an encounter with an enemy. However, when I try to reference the Party class instantiated in the `Main` function, I am thrown an error stating `The name 'PlayerTeam' does not exist in the current context.` Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Showing us the related code is always a good way to start. As you said yourself, you instantiated your class in the ```main``` method. Your new function doesn't know it exists without you telling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! Since a `Main` method is always static, any non-local variables referenced in the `Main` method must also be static. Mark your `PlayerTeam` variable as static.

```cs
// change this:
// public Party PlayerTream
// to this:
public static Party PlayerTeam;
```

Longer term, you will want to create some sort of Game object and have it create all of your state, rather than having static variables all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the declaration of `PlayerTeam` from inside your `Main()` method out to CLASS level so that it is accessible from anywhere:

```
public static Party PlayerTeam;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PlayerTeam = new Party();

}
```